# Intersection of a family of non-empty closed intervals

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to make sense of this in my head. I know that the nested interval theorem proves the following if the intervals are bounded, but what if they are unbounded? I apologize for my ignorance to type mathematical symbols on this editor.

Let *I* be a family of non-empty closed intervals, and suppose that *I* has the finite intersection property. Is it true that the intersection of all *I* is necessarily non empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the family of unbounded intervals defined by
$$I_n = [n,+\infty),\qquad n=1,2,\dots$$
On the one hand, the intersection of a finite number of these intervals is nonempty.
Explicitly, the intersection of the intervals $I_{n_1},I_{n_2},\dots,I_{n_k}$ is
$$I_{n_1}\cap I_{n_2}\cap \cdots \cap I_{n_k} = I_{\max(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k)}\neq\varnothing.$$
On the other hand, the intersection of all the intervals is empty because any number is contained in only finitely many of them.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a ton and totally makes sense, and that's kind of what I had previously thought. I have been trying to figure out how to prove that the latter intersection is empty. I can only find references to nested intervals but not to an interval like the one you provided. Could you tell me how you would prove this?

Comment: Sure. Suppose the intersection is nonempty. Then there is some number, say $x$, contained in the intersection. Now pick an integer greater than $x$, say $n$ (explicitly you could take $n=\lceil x\rceil + 1$). Then $x$ is not contained in the interval $I_n$, a contradiction since we assumed it was contained in all the intervals. Does that make sense?

Comment: It almost does. what i don't understand is that if we have a bunch of intervals from n to infinity, and say we go up to the interval nsubx to infinity, then the interval nsubx + 1 to infinity is still in the intersection of all of them because they all include infinity. So I don't know how there can be any number that is not contained in infinity. Does my question make sense?

Comment: Let me give it another shot. The point is that we're taking the intersection of *all* the intervals. It is true that if you stop after taking a finite intersection you'll have an infinite interval that's left over. But we're intersecting everything. Informally, the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty[n,\infty)$ is like the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}[n,\infty)$. The limit is $\varnothing$ because  if you carry out the intersection far enough you'll eventually remove any arbitrary number.

Comment: You rock @user134824 , thank you.

Comment: If you can, will you look at my new question here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717687/does-fx-f1-x-for-all-x-in-domain-of-f-for-this-specific-fx
?