# does F(x) = -F(1/x) for all x in domain of F for this specific F(x)?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I apologize in advance for my ignorance on how to type mathematical symbols in this editor.

Let F be the function defined for $x > 0$ by
$F(x)= \int_1^x e^{((t^2)+1)/t}\frac{dt}{t}$
Show that $F(x) = -F(1/x)$ for all $x$ in domain of $F$.

What I have done is used the mean value theorem for integrals to say that there exists a number $z$ such that:
$e^{((z^2)+1)/z} \cdot \int_1^x\frac{dt}{t} = e^{((z^2)+1)/z} \cdot (-1)\cdot\int_1^{1/x}\frac{dt}{t}$ and that they both equal $e^{((z^2)+1)/z}\ln|x|$.

What i can't figure out is how to show that the $z$ used for the first function ($F(x)$) is the same as the $z$ used in the second function ($-F(1/x)$).

Does anyone know how I could go about it?

thank you.

Comment: How is $F$ defined on $x>0$, when the integral starts from $1$? Isn't $F$ defined on $x\geq 1$?

Comment: @frabala You can have $0<x<1$: the upper limit of integration can be less than the lower limit. But we need $x>0$ so that we don't divide by zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, write the integral this way:
$$
F(x) = \int_1^x e^{t + 1/t}\frac{dt}{t}.
$$
Now we'll try the $u$-substitution $u=1/t$. Then $dt=-du/u^2$ and the new integral is
$$
F(x)=\int_1^{1/x} e^{1/u+u}\cdot\frac{-du/u^2}{1/u}
= -\int_1^{1/x}e^{u+1/u}\frac{du}{u} = -F(1/x).
$$

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I tried using u=1/t but i didn't get anywhere with it. I can't use it in the original integral because i'll keep a t dependence on the exponent. Maybe i missed something? what I was planning on doing was to somehow make the limits of integration from 1 to x and from 1 to 1/x the same, but even this doesn't make sense as it would make the function = 0 where it's not defined.

Comment: Sorry i keep coming back to you, but could you loor at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785458/error-replacing-integral-of-f-with-its-midpoint-rule-approximation