# Error replacing integral of f with its midpoint rule approximation

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

here is a question I've been banging my head against.

If f is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b), and if there is a positive real number M such that |f'(t)| is less than or equal to M for all t in (a,b), then the error in replacing the integral from a to b of f(t)dt with its midpoint rule approximation using n subdivisions of equal width does not exceed (M(b-a)^2)/(4n).

Note that it's not given that f even has a second derivative at any point of (a,b), so we may not make any use of a second derivative of f in the argument

I keep thinking I have to use the mean value theorem, but don't know how to apply it in this sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll do the case $n=1$; the general case has one extra step, namely   summing over $n$ subintervals.

The mean value theorem is indeed used here. It shows that $f$ is *Lipschitz*, that is $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in [a,b]$. The Lipschitz property  is what we actually  need for error estimate, not derivative itself.

Let $x^*$ be the midpoint of $[a,b]$. For every $x\in [a,b]$ we have 
$$ f(x^*)-M|x-x^*|\le f(x)\le f(x^*)+M|x-x^*|$$
Integrate this inequality over $x$ in $[a,b]$, noting that
$$\int_a^b |x-x^*| \,dx = 2 \int_{x^*}^b (x-x^*)\,dx =  (b-x^*)^2 =\frac14(b-a)^2 $$
Thus, $$ (b-a)f(x^*)- \frac{M}{4}(b-a)^2 \le \int_a^b f(x)\,dx\le (b-a)f(x^*)+ \frac{M}{4}(b-a)^2$$
which is the desired estimate for $n=1$.

Comment: Thank you, however, i am not allowed to use properties which we havent proven yet, in this case the lipschitz property. Do you have any other ideas? I was trying to break up the midpoint rule into left and right hand rule and adding them together but i am having problems making the total error < than what the problem stated

Comment: @nvn Don't call it the Lipschitz property, then.  It's an immediate consequence of the mean value theorem. Prove it in one line, and then use it.

Comment: The same error bound is valid for the trapezoidal rule: see [pdf](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3219088?uid=3738296&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103987157547) p. 305 .