# Correctness of Nested Intersection Property proof

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Given that $\{I_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence of non-empty closed intervals, i.e. $I_{n+1} \subset I_n \ \forall n\geq 1$, show that $\cap_{n \geq 1} I_n$ is a closed non-empty interval.

My attempt:

1) $\exists \ a \in I_{n+1} \text{st} \ a \in I_n$ because $I_{n+1} \subset I_n$

2) $\Rightarrow a \in I_{n+1} \cap I_n$

3) $\Rightarrow a \in I_n \forall n \geq 1$

4) $\cap_{n \geq 1} I_n \neq \emptyset$

I have just realized that I have not shown that it is also closed. Not sure how I would show that. That there is no epsilon neighborhood around the end points of the intersection? (that is if it is not a single point). I mean.. it will have epsilon neighbour hood but only on one side.

Comment: How does step 3) follows (rigorously) from step 2)?

Comment: because 1) implies that $I_n \subset I_{n-1}$ and so on

Comment: ok, I see. this would not work

Comment: Please check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712833/intersection-of-a-family-of-non-empty-closed-intervals and add to your assumptions that the intervals $I_n$ are bounded (at least, for $n \ge n_0$).

Comment: In steps 1 and 2 you have not stated what values of n are referred to . All of them? Some of them?